# Does maxscale (with Galera) handle Non-primary component/node condition automatically?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, galera, mysql-proxy, maxscale

We are going to use maxscale as a sql proxy with our mariadb database, with Galera cluster.

In Galera cluster, when quorum is not achieved and split-brain condition happens, some node becomes Non-primary. The Non-primary nodes start rejecting queries coming to them.(as per document)

Does maxscale automatically handle this and stops sending queries to non-primary nodes until they become primary component again.?

I have tested one thing that if any node goes down, maxscale handles that properly and stops sending queries to that node. My question is, does it do same for Non-primary nodes too? If not how to handle it.

PS: I am actually not able to test the non-primary thing myself that's why I am asking this question here. It would be great if somebody can help me achieve and test this situation myself too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Galera monitoring in MaxScale will handle split-brain situations. The monitoring in MaxScale will use the cluster UUID to detect which nodes are a part of it.

For more information, refer to the [`galeramon`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-maxscale-25-galera-monitor/) documentation.